# Rearranging UI elements according to screen size in Flutter

Tags: flutter, web, dart, flutter-layout

I checked flutter interact 19 keynote video where it was mentioned an upcoming feature to resize and rearrange the ui according to screen size. It is in this video, minute 17:30.

https://youtu.be/NfNdXgJZfFo

6 months ago it was in "very early stage" does anybody know if it is out yet? I believe is something  else than LayoutBuilder or MediaQuery.of(), since those were available before the keynote on the video.

I know there are other packages as well from other developers but I am interested in the one from Google.

Answer (score -1):

I am using `MediaQuery.of(context).size;` in my project in the stable channel to change the layout depending on the width. It works for me without problems. I have written a widget that distinguishes between large screen (tablet) and small screen (smartphone).

```dart
class ScreenWidthBuilder extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget Function(BuildContext context, bool isAWideScreen)  builder;
  final int bigScreenUpFrom;

  const ScreenWidthBuilder({Key key, @required this.builder, this.bigScreenUpFrom = 600}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    // screenSize.width changes depending on screen orientation
    bool isAWideScreen = screenSize.width >= this.bigScreenUpFrom;
    return this.builder(context, isAWideScreen);
  }
}
```

First I tried to use the `LayoutBuilder` widget but I was able to achieve a better result with `MediaQuery.of(context).size;`. With MediaQuery you can request many data about the device screen (size, textScaleFactor, orientation, etc).

For more information have a look at:

- Documentation of [LayoutBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html)
- Documentation of [MediaQuery](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html) and [MediaQueryData](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQueryData-class.html) that gets returned from `MediaQuery.of(context)`.